# Ubuntu 19.10 Sound Issues

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 19.10

I wonder if anyone can help with my sound issue please.  I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 (I always choose the minimal option) and this issue did not happen in 18.04 or 19.04.

My machine has a Radeon RX 580 Series Graphics card and a Realtek sound card. For some reason the sound always defaulted to the Ellesmere HDMI RX580 and I had to change the sound settings each time I switch the machine on.

I searched the forums and followed the answer to a similar question and installed Pulse Audio Volume Control, and went to the last tab and made sure the HDMI Profile was set to off:

[image]

However, which things have improved, I'm still finding randomly applications seems to go back to trying to using the HDMI audio and I have to go back into Pulse Audio Volume Control and set the HDMI profile to Off.

Has anyone experienced anything similar, and do you think I need to raise a bug report, or am I doing something wrong?

Please let me know if you need anymore logs or reports.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that you're not going to use your GPU's HDMI sound at all, one way to make sure it can't be selected automatically would be blacklisting the HDMI sound module.

Open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Enter your password and append the following on a new line at the end of the file:

```
blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi
```

(Use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `V` to paste it and then save the file with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `O` and close it with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `X`.)

Afterward, just reboot and the HDMI sound option should be gone. In case you need it again, just remove the line from the file and reboot again.